# How to handle Stripe Webhook signing Secret Key rotation on the server side

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

From the following Stripe's documentation of Webhooks, it is visible that the webhook signing secret key will be rotated within max 24-hour of duration - https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets

Now if we are storing this secret on the server side to verify the webhook signatures, it becomes troublesome to manually update this key on the server every 24 hours.

- Is there any way to disable the rotating of this signing secret key automatically?
- If not, is there any API through which we can fetch this signing secret key in the server?
- If not, then how can we handle this scenario where the signing secret key is rotating every 24 hours, and if we do not want to manually update it on our server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss-reading the documentation. The webhook secret key doesn't expire unless you want to roll it out by your self (via your dashboard). If so you can choose to roll it out immediately so you can update the new value in your server immediately too or delay its expiration up to 24h[1]. In the case of adding a delay you need to considering verifying using the too secret keys (new and old one)[2] so that you have enough time to rollout the new values in your servers.

[1] [https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets:~:text=You%20can%20choose%20to%20immediately%20expire%20the%20current%20secret%20or%20delay%20its%20expiration%20for%20up%20to%2024%20hours%20to%20allow%20yourself%20time%20to%20update%20the%20verification%20code%20on%20your%20server](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets:%7E:text=You%20can%20choose%20to%20immediately%20expire%20the%20current%20secret%20or%20delay%20its%20expiration%20for%20up%20to%2024%20hours%20to%20allow%20yourself%20time%20to%20update%20the%20verification%20code%20on%20your%20server)

[2] [https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets:~:text=During%20this%20time%2C%20multiple%20secrets%20are%20active%20for%20the%20endpoint.%20Stripe%20generates%20one%20signature%20per%20secret%20until%20expiration](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#roll-endpoint-secrets:%7E:text=During%20this%20time%2C%20multiple%20secrets%20are%20active%20for%20the%20endpoint.%20Stripe%20generates%20one%20signature%20per%20secret%20until%20expiration).

Comment: Thanks @os4m37, so you mean that if we manually want to rollout the webhook signing secret key, then max we could choose is 24 hours to get that new key effective? And Stripe will never rollout that key automatically for us?

Comment: Yes exactly. Stripe don't rollout automatically the key unless you request that explicitly from Dashboard.

Comment: Great thanks, I was confused about those wordings in the documentation. But I didn't find anywhere else that it won't expire the keys automatically.